# TPL TaskFactory.FromAsync vs Tasks with blocking methods

Tags: c#-4.0, task, task-parallel-library, networkstream, taskfactory

I was wondering if there were any performance implications between using TPL `TaskFactory.FromAsync` and using `TaskFactory.StartNew` on blocking versions of the methods. I'm writing a TCP server that will support no more than 100 concurrent connections. After writing code with the first option & chaining multiple read & write operations with continue with, I was left with ugly, hard to debug code.

I believe writing code with the synchronous version & then wrapping it with a Task would decrease complexity & increase testability, but I'm worried about the performance implications of doing this.

For example, are there any performance differences between these 2 calls:

```
NetworkStream stream;
byte[] data;
int bytesRead;

//using FromAsync
Task<int> readChunk = Task<int>.Factory.FromAsync (
      stream.BeginRead, stream.EndRead,
      data, bytesRead, data.Length - bytesRead, null);

//using StartNew with blocking version
Task<int> readChunk2 = Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(() => 
      stream.Read(data, bytesRead, data.Length - bytesRead));
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You *absolutely* want to use `FromAsync` when an API offers a BeginXXX/EndXXX version of a method. The difference is that, in the case of something like `Stream` or `Socket` or `WebRequest`, you'll actually end up using async I/O underneath the covers (e.g. I/O Completion Ports on Windows) which is far more efficient than blocking multiple CPU threads doing a synchronous operation. These methods provide the best way to achieve I/O scalability.

Check out this section of the .NET SDK on MSDN entitled [TPL and Traditional .NET Asynchronous Programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997423.aspx) for more information on how to combine these two programming models to achieve async nirvana.

Comment: Do you have any sources which say calling a web method (for example) using Begin/End with Async is better than using the synchronous version with Async?  What you say makes sense, I just like to read it somewhere official.

Answer (score 5):

Following a copy from a external link:

> Yes. In .NET 4, the Task Parallel Library includes a built in wrapper
>   for the APM pattern (Begin/End): Task.Factory.FromAsync.  For example,
>   if you wanted to create a task for a call to Stream's
>   BeginRead/EndRead method, you could do:

```
Stream s = ...;
byte [] buffer = ...;
Task<int> numBytesRead = Task<int>.Factory.FromAsync(s.BeginRead, s.EndRead, buffer, 0, buffer.Length, null);
// or with await
int numBytesRead = await Task<int>.Factory.FromAsync(s.BeginRead, s.EndRead, buffer, 0, buffer.Length, null);
```

> Under the covers, FromAsync is just built on top of TaskCompletionSource.  A simple version of FromAsync for this read example would look something like:

```
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<TResult>();
s.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, iar =>
{
    try { tcs.SetResult(s.EndRead(iar)); }
    catch(Exception exc) { tcs.SetException(exc); }
}, null);
Task<int> numBytesRead = tcs.Task;
```

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/async/thread/ed8a14e8-d19a-42d1-bc3f-7017bdfed09c

Comment: please provide content of external links. Otherwise  your answer is worthless if the link breaks.

Comment: if msdn breaks, we are all worthless