# How to disconnect SignalR form client side to achieve timeout funcitonality

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, signalr, signalr.client

I have client-side code that sends requests to server for some data. Sometime server don't respond and it take too long to establish connection. I want to set some timeout functionality on client-side so after that timeout, client will stop to try connecting server. In simple web request we can use timeout functionality. For example I am using the following code somewhere else and it is working fine for non-signalr request.

But when I send request through signalr, I can not set timeout to end this request and show user a message that data could not be fetched from server.
On this site someone suggested "Send a specific string to the client to force the disconnect" but that is not my scenario. I want to handle it on client side.

```
var refit = RestService.For<SomeApi>(new HttpClient
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri(BASE_URL),
    Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)
});
```

Comment: Or I cay say in simple words, i want to call something like HubConnection.close() if client could not connect to server in 30 seconds.

Comment: Don't you want to call hubConnection.StopAsync();

Comment: I think i need something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10409357/safely-stop-long-running-task           but I don't know how can I use it in my case.